# SDK not found in Xcode 8 when I add in base SDK it shows this

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sdk, ios-simulator

To test my project on iPhone 4S I have installed the iOS 9.3 in Xcode 8 but when I mention iphoneos(9.3) in base SDK it shows "SDK not found". I also have changed my deployment target to 9.3. Kindly share your ideas. 
[image]

**I also face this error while build:**
 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me many times I don't even know why this appears but when I build my app and quit Xcode and again restart Xcode and open my app then build then Run go and enjoy everything becomes fine.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 4S no more support in Xcode 8.
More details please  check [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61259)